# Elementary fact about compact (non-compact) topological/Lie groups

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, compactness

Can one formulate a proof of this (apparently simple) fact?

**Statement**: Let $G$ a topological group and $H\leq G$ a topological subgroup isomorphic to a non-compact topological group $N$. Then $G$ is non-compact as a topological group.

My attempt: A topology $\{U_i\}$ on $H$ is the subspace topology inherited from the topology $\{V_i\}$ of $G$. Then how does it follow that an open cover of $G$ is necessarily infinite?

Comment: This statement is not true.  Maybe you are missing some hypotheses?  Also, when you say "isomorphic" do you mean as groups or as topological groups?

Comment: As topological groups (algebraic isomorphism + homeomorphism). I want a general proof that $O(n,p;\mathbb{R})$ - the orthogonal group of $\mathbb{R}^n$ endowed with a bilinear form with n times +1 and p times -1 is not compact in whatever metric topology.

Comment: So I need to quote this result, because I can show that $O(1,1;\mathbb{R})$ is not compact in a norm topology.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan: No, it has a proper subgroup isomorphic to a noncompact group.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misread the question. You can show fairly explicitly that the indefinite orthogonal groups are noncompact by showing that they aren't bounded, since for subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ compact is equivalent to closed and bounded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not true in general.  For instance, if $G=S^1$, then $H=\{\exp(2\pi i t):t\in\mathbb{Q}\}$ is a subgroup of $G$ that is not compact even though $G$ is compact.

It is true if you assume $H$ is closed in $G$, since any closed subspace of a compact space is compact so if $G$ were compact then $H$ would be compact as well.

Comment: Then I need to show that $O(1.1;\mathbb{R})$ is closed in $O(n.p;\mathbb{R})$, for arbitrary n,p. Any ideas?